# sh: start-storybook: command not found in macOS

Tags: typescript, storybook, pnpm

I have added this command in `package.json`:

```
"storybook": "start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook"
```

then run this command: `pnpm run storybook`, shows error like this:

```
> pnpm run storybook

> ui-component@0.1.53 storybook /Users/john/source/frontend/ui-component
> start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook

sh: start-storybook: command not found
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed.
```

I have tried to install the dependencies follow this issue https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/311 and restart the visual studio code, still could not work. this is the dependencies I have already tried:

```
> pnpm list|grep "storybook"
@storybook/cli 7.0.10
@storybook/react 7.0.10
@storybook/react-vite 7.0.10
```

I also tried to use the `sb` command still did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the tutorial are the old version storybook config, the 7+ version of storybook are migrate from `start-storybook` to `storybook dev`: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#start-storybook--build-storybook-binaries-removed

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command applied for me to solve this issue based on migration document provided [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#start-storybook--build-storybook-binaries-removed):

```
npx storybook@latest upgrade --prerelease
```

Later yess to all (but always read if the solution provided by the CLI upgrade make sense for your current project/stack)